# Export PDF/Excel in Datatable jquery

Tags: jquery, excel, pdf, datatable

I have problem with export PDF and excel in data table using jquery for firefox its asking flash player to enable pdf and excel button but in chrome its coming default 
I need to export pdf and excel using data table without flash player

Comment: http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/3871/table-tools-v2-copyxlscsvpdf-dont-work/p2 should help `:)`

Comment: SO doesn't exist to write your project for you. I just researched this a few weeks ago and found answers. I used Google.

Answer (score 2):

I have recently worked with Datatable Tablettool plugin.It uses alivepdf and zeroclipboard for exporting data to pdf and excel respectively.Both are asction script files compiled into swf and injected to tabltools.If you belive your artifacts should never include flash(which is rare because today flash have same if not more demand like javascript) then you can use

**JXLS** for excel export [offical site](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/)

**iTEXT** for pdf export  [offical site](http://itextpdf.com/index.php)

Else if you want to stick to tabletool swf plugin you may find below example useful